# Помогите отредактировать код на php

Tags: php, веб-скрейпинг

```
$a = $steamprofile['profileurl'];
    if (file_exists('cache.html') && time() - filemtime('cache.html') < 3600) {
    $get_content = file_get_contents('cache.html');

      } else {
        $get_content = file_get_contents("$a/inventory/json/730/2");
         $content = $get_content;
    file_put_contents('cache.html', $content);
            }
    $data_image = (array) json_decode($get_content) -> rgInventory;
    $count_content = count($data_image);
    $data_content = (array) json_decode($get_content, TRUE);
    echo "Total items: $count_content <br><br>";
for ($i=0; $i<$count_content; $i++) {
    $element_name = array_shift($data_content[rgInventory]);
    $name_item = "$element_name[classid]_$element_name[instanceid]";
    echo "<img src='http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/";
    print_r($data_content['rgDescriptions'][$name_item]['icon_url']);
    echo "' style='width:90px; height:90px; float:left; margin: 5px; outline: 1px solid black;'>";
                                    }
}
```

**Суть его в том, что-бы подключиться к сайту Steam, взять один раз информацию через OpenID и записать ее в файл cache.html. Проблема  в том, что информация сохраняется и для другого пользователя**

> т.е если Ваня авторизовался на сайте и сможет просмотреть информацию
>   о себе, то тот же Петя уже будет видеть информацию о Ване, но никак не
>   о себе

Comment: А где здесь параметры, отвечающие за текущего пользователя? Что-то не вижу...

Comment: Я не имею ни малейшего понятия как туда вставить параметры

Comment: Ну раз ни малейшего, то вам тогда на обучающие ресурсы, так как рекомендации об использовании сессии или "ID пользователя" вам мало чем помогут.